# django-websocket-redis does not publish message

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis

I am a newbie to django-websocket-redis and can't use it to publish messages. heartbeat messages are received but about published message from back-end, just last message is received by front-end (after page reload) and other messages are ignored. here is my code structure:

```
-mysite 
   |- __init__.py
   |-settings.py
   |-urls.py
   |-wsgi.py
-websockets
   |-migrations
       |-__init__.py
   |-templates
       |-index.html
   |-__init__.py
   |-admin.py
   |-models.py
   |-tests.py
   |-urls.py
   |-views.py
-db.sqlite3
-manage.py
```

and settings.py:

```
    import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
SITE_ID = 1
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
SECRET_KEY = 'super.secret'
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = os.environ.get('DJANGO_STATIC_ROOT', '')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'redis_sessions.session'
SESSION_REDIS_PREFIX = 'session'
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.core.context_processors.static',
     'django.core.context_processors.request',
     'ws4redis.context_processors.default',
)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ws4redis',
    'websockets',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ws4redis.django_runserver.application'
WEBSOCKET_URL = '/ws/'
WS4REDIS_EXPIRE = 3600
WS4REDIS_HEARTBEAT = '--heartbeat--'
WS4REDIS_PREFIX = 'demo'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s %(module)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'simple',
    },
},
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

websockets/views.py:

```
class BroadcastChatView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'websockets/index.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    welcome = RedisMessage('Hello everybody')  # create a welcome message to be sent to everybody
    RedisPublisher(facility='foobar', broadcast=True).publish_message(welcome)
    return super(BroadcastChatView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

websockets/index.html:

```
<div id="billboard"></div>
<button type="button" id="send_message">click to send message</button>
<!--<input type="text" id="text_message">-->

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/ws4redis.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var ws4redis = WS4Redis({
        uri: ' ws://localhost:8080/ws/foobar?subscribe-broadcast&publish-broadcast&echo',
        receive_message: receiveMessage,
        heartbeat_msg: {{ WS4REDIS_HEARTBEAT }}

    });
    var billboard = $('#billboard');

    // attach this function to an event handler on your site
    function sendMessage() {
        ws4redis.send_message('A message');
    }

    // receive a message though the websocket from the server
    function receiveMessage(msg) {
        console.log('Message from Websocket: ' + msg);
        billboard.append('<br/>' + msg);
        billboard.scrollTop(billboard.scrollTop() + 25);
    }

    $('#send_message').click(function() {
        ws4redis.send_message("hello");
    });

});
</script>
```

and mysite/wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from ws4redis.uwsgi_runserver import uWSGIWebsocketServer

_django_app = get_wsgi_application()
_websocket_app = uWSGIWebsocketServer()


def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ.get('PATH_INFO').startswith(settings.WEBSOCKET_URL):
        return _websocket_app(environ, start_response)
    return _django_app(environ, start_response)
```